# im learning backend route its all ok for first time but when i go back for the second time the site cant be reach

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: terminal]

[image]

if I go to the home page then I go to the contact page I go back again to the home page it says the site can't be reached

```
var http = require("http");

http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.url);
    const url = req.url;

    if (url === "/") {
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      res.write("<h1 style = color:red>this is home</h1> <p>marzzuk</p>");
      res.end();
    }

    if (url === "/contact") {
      res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      res.write("<h1 style = color:red>this is contact</h1>");
      res.end();
    } else {
      res.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
      res.write("<h1 style = color:red>404</h1>");
      res.end();
    }
  })
  .listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple logic issue.

If the URL is `/` then both the first `if` and the `else` condition are true with the latter trying to write to the response after it has been *ended*.

Isolate your logic branches to avoid crashing the server

```js
switch (url) {
  case "/":
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    res.write(`<h1 style="color:red">this is home</h1> <p>marzzuk</p>`);
    return res.end();
  case "/contact":
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    res.write(`<h1 style="color:red">this is contact</h1>`);
    return res.end();
  default:
    res.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    res.write(`<h1 style="color:red">404</h1>`);
    return res.end();
}
```